# How can I search for SiteName and SiteURL associated with my Sharepoint hub site using PnP Modern Search?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, sharepoint-search, hub-site, pnp-search-webparts

I am using PnP modern search for Sharepoint Online hub site, the hub site has around 100 associated sites. I need a query which return the result if `SiteName` or `SiteURL` contains that search terms.

For eg, if my `searchTerms` is CLG, so I expect the result returned should either have that `searchTerm` in `SiteName` or `SiteTitle`

Currently I have query which return result only for `SiteName`

```
{searchTerms} contentclass:sts_site Path:"https://dummy01.sharepoint.com/sites/MyHubSite"
```

I tried query like

```
 {searchTerms} contentclass:sts_site spsiteurl:/sites/ {searchTerms} Path:"https://dummy01.sharepoint.com/sites/MyHubSite"
```

Comment: Try if this query works for you `ContentClass:STS_Site (SiteName:{searchTerms}* OR SiteTitle:{searchTerms}*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get desired result with below query

```
spsiteurl:/sites/{searchTerms} OR {searchTerms} contentclass:sts_site
Path:"https://dummy01.sharepoint.com/sites/MyHubSite"
```